# Using Serilog.ILogger in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, logging, serilog

I'm trying to use use Serilog.ILogger in my Azure function. I'm setting it up so I can add custom properties down the line. When I try to run the Azure function a console window pops up and shows the following error:

[image: Error Message]

> [2021-03-16T00:15:25.424Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '6a853374-f99b-4ca4-8bde-8df8cc1e7e79'.
> [2021-03-16T00:15:25.426Z] func: Invalid host services. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: The following service registrations did not match the expected services:
> [2021-03-16T00:15:25.427Z]   [Missing] ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider, Lifetime: Singleton, ImplementationType: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Diagnostics.FunctionFileLoggerProvider, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

This is the code that I'm using in my startup:

```
 public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var serilogLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(TelemetryConverter.Traces)
            .CreateLogger();
        builder
            .Services
            .AddHttpClient()
            .AddLogging(l =>
            {
                l.ClearProviders();
                l.AddSerilog(serilogLogger);
            })
            .AddSingleton(serilogLogger); 
   }
```

I'm also injecting an instance of ILogger<> into a few classes in my function too.

Any thoughts of what might be going wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following code?

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Configuration;
using Serilog.Events;


var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithComponentName(ComponentName)
                .Enrich.WithVersion()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.AzureApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey)
                .CreateLogger();


 builder.Services.AddLogging(l =>
 {
    l.ClearProvidersExceptFunctionProviders();
    l.AddSerilog(logger);
 });
```

Comment: It seems that this requires installing the Arcus Observability nuget package. Is there a way to do it without that?

Comment: @HEldursi Have a look [here](https://github.com/arcus-azure/arcus.observability/blob/master/src/Arcus.Observability.Telemetry.AzureFunctions/Extensions/ILoggerBuilderExtensions.cs)

Comment: We also provide templates for you to scaffold projects https://templates.arcus-azure.net/